# Minecraft suddenly crashing when opening container

Tags: opengl, minecraft

I have been playing Minecraft on my HP Pavillion for over 2 years and suddenly the other day it started crashing. When I went through the logs, I found an error that when I search it on google is said to be a 'video driver' issue. Has something changed recently in either the openGL or Radeon drivers?

Error from launcher logs:

```
[Info: 2019-07-09 23:00:47.099781657: GameCallbacks.cpp(138)] Launcher/launcher 
(main) Info 
../src/gallium/drivers/r600/sb/sb_ir.cpp:340:update_packed_items: Assertion `!sw p[chan] || swp[chan] == v' failed.
[Info: 2019-07-09 23:00:47.099916121: GameCallbacks.cpp(138)] Launcher/monitor (Process Monitor) Fatal Process crashed with exit code 6
[Info: 2019-07-09 23:00:47.102898019: GameController.cpp(330)] Game closed with id 1
[Info: 2019-07-09 23:00:47.103385699: NetQueue.cpp(529)] NetQueue: Starting net action http://hopper.minecraft.net/crashes/submit_report/
[Info: 2019-07-09 23:00:47.324936561: NetQueue.cpp(396)] NetQueue: Primary ip: 50.19.104.190, Url: hopper.minecraft.net
[Info: 2019-07-09 23:00:47.325115228: NetQueue.cpp(428)] NetQueue: Action failed with result "The requested URL returned error: 400 BAD REQUEST" (22) : http://hopper.minecraft.net/crashes/submit_report/
[Info: 2019-07-09 23:00:47.325137917: NetQueue.cpp(467)] NetQueue: Action finished: http://hopper.minecraft.net/crashes/submit_report/
[Info: 2019-07-09 23:00:47.325324168: GameCallbacks.cpp(33)] Destroying GameCallbacks!
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it still broken? I don't know enough about your system to pinpoint exactly, but here are some things you can try:

#### Java 8

As per the current official [software requirements](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948) from Mojang, Minecraft requires Java 8. Using other versions *may* work, but there could be pitfalls. Therefore:

1. Make sure you have Java 8 installed, if not, install it:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

2. Make sure Java 8 is the default Java version for your system:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Choose Java 8 if there are any alternatives.

#### Driver

You should be running on the open source AMD drivers (called ATI) if you have a default system. Make sure the driver is up to date.

If at this point it still doesn't work, you might try installing a proprietary driver, but beware; proprietary drivers are no longer available, supported, or updated for older cards.

#### OpenGL

As per the hardware requirements, you will need a graphics card with OpenGL 4.4 support. Some really old graphics cards don't support this so make sure your graphics card supports OpenGL 4.4. If it doesn't, you will need to upgrade to a better GPU or play on an older version of Minecraft (versions pre 1.12 seem to require [OpenGL 3.1](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Java_Edition_hardware_requirements&oldid=1097746) and even older require only [OpenGL 1.3](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Java_Edition_hardware_requirements&oldid=1028338)).

---

If all else fails, and your system is within the hardware and software requirements, you could try sending a [bug report to Mojang](https://bugs.mojang.com/projects/MC/summary).

Comment: thanks, I'll give some of those a try later tonight. I haven't played it in weeks because I couldn't open a container without it crashing